# awk to get first column if the a specific number in the line is greater than a digit

Tags: shell, awk

I have a data file (`file.txt`) contains the below lines:

```
123 pro=tegs, ETA=12:00, team=xyz,user1=tom,dom=dby.com
345 pro=rbs, team=abc,user1=chan,dom=sbc.int,ETA=23:00
456 team=efg, pro=bvy,ETA=22:00,dom=sss.co.uk,user2=lis
```

I'm expecting to get the first column (`$1`) only if the `ETA=` number is greater than 15, like here I will have 2nd and 3rd line first column only is expected.

```
345
456
```

I tried like `cat file.txt | awk -F [,TPF=]' '{print $1}'` but its print whole line which has ETA at the end.

Comment: $1 is the first field, but you path the string `[,TPF=]` as field separator, and this string does not occur anywhere in your file. Therefore the first field equals the whole line. BTW, the command you posted has an unbalanced single quote, so it would not even execute.

Comment: @user1934428 FYI `[,TPF=]` in that context isn't a string, it's a bracket expression containing 5 characters, so the record would be split into fields at every `T`, `=`, etc.

Comment: @EdMorton : Ah, you are right. I forgot that the field separator can be a regular expression.  Thank you for reminding me. But in this case, the output should not be the **whole line**, as the OP claimed, but the part of the line before the first comma (assuming that the input is exactly as posted). Can you explain how `print $1` could print the whole line?

Comment: @user1934428 That script in the question has a syntax error (missing `'` before `[,TPF=]'`) so it can't print anything. idk what the script was that printed a whole line for the OP but if you fixed the syntax error, that script wouldn't do that, it'd print up to the first `=` from the line shown in the example.

Comment: @EdMorton : Yes, this is what I told the OP too. It might well be this error is not present in the original code; perhaps the OP retyped the command instead of properly copying. The whole question is pretty unclear, and perhaps should be closed.

Answer (score 4):

Using `awk`

```
$ awk -F"[=, ]" '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) if ($i=="ETA") if ($(i+1) > 15) print $1}' input_file
345
456
```

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples please try following GNU `awk` code. Using `match` function of GNU `awk` where I am using regex `(^[0-9]+).*ETA=([0-9]+):[0-9]+` which creates 2 capturing groups and saves its values into array arr. Then checking condition if 2nd element of arr is greater than 15 then print 1st value of arr array as per requirement.

```bash
awk '
match($0,/(^[0-9]+).*\<ETA=([0-9]+):[0-9]+/,arr) && arr[2]+0>15{
  print arr[1]
}
' Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
123 pro=tegs, ETA=12:00, team=xyz,user1=tom,dom=dby.com
345 pro=rbs, team=abc,user1=chan,dom=sbc.int,ETA=23:00
456 team=efg, pro=bvy,ETA=02:00,dom=sss.co.uk,user2=lis
```

then

```
awk 'substr($0,index($0,"ETA=")+4,2)+0>15{print $1}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
345
```

Explanation: I use [String functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html), `index` to find where is `ETA=` then `substr` to get 2 characters after `ETA=`, 4 is used as `ETA=` is 4 characters long and `index` gives start position, I use `+0` to convert to integer then compare it with `15`. Disclaimer: this solution assumes every row has `ETA=` followed by exactly 2 digits.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Comment: `index($0,"ETA=")` would fail if the input could contain `PETA=` or similar before the `ETA=` string.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever input contains `tag=value` pairs as yours does, it's best to first create an array of those mappings (`v[]`) below and then you can just access the values by their tags (names):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS = "[, =]+"
    OFS = ","
}
{
    delete v
    for ( i=2; i<NF; i+=2 ) {
        v[$i] = $(i+1)
    }
}
v["ETA"]+0 > 15 {
    print $1
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
345
456
```

With that approach you can trivially enhance the script in future to access whatever values you like by their names, test them in whatever combinations you like, output them in whatever order you like, etc. For example:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS = "[, =]+"
    OFS = ","
}
{
    delete v
    for ( i=2; i<NF; i+=2 ) {
        v[$i] = $(i+1)
    }
}
(v["pro"] ~ /b/) && (v["ETA"]+0 > 15) {
    print $1, v["team"], v["dom"]
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
345,abc,sbc.int
456,efg,sss.co.uk
```

Think about how you'd enhance any other solution to do the above or anything remotely similar.

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear why you think your attempt would do anything of the sort. Your attempt uses a completely different field separator and does not compare anything against the number 15.

You'll also want to get rid of the [useless use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat).

When you specify a column separator with `-F` that changes what the first column `$1` actually means; it is then everything before the first occurrence of the separator. Probably separately `split` the line to obtain the first column, space-separated.

```
awk -F 'ETA=' '$2 > 15 { split($0, n, /[ \t]+/); print n[1] }' file.txt
```

The value in `$2` will be the data after the first separator (and up until the next one) but using it in a numeric comparison simply ignores any non-numeric text after the number at the beginning of the field. So for example, on the first line, we are actually literally checking if `12:00, team=xyz,user1=tom,dom=dby.com` is larger than 15 but it effectively checks if 12 is larger than 15 (which is obviously false).

When the condition is true, we split the original line `$0` into the array `n` on sequences of whitespace, and then print the first element of this array.

Comment: `-F 'ETA='` would fail if the input could contain `PETA=` or similar.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk` you could match `ETA=` followed by 1 or more digits. Then get the match without the ETA= part and check if the number is greater than 15 and print the first field.

```
awk '/^[0-9]/ && match($0, /ETA=[0-9]+/) {
  if(substr($0, RSTART+4, RLENGTH-4)+0 > 15) print $1
}' file
```

Output

```
345
456
```

If the first field should start with a number:

```
awk '/^[0-9]/ && match($0, /ETA=[0-9]+/) {
  if(substr($0, RSTART+4, RLENGTH-4) > 15)+0 print $1
}' file
```

Comment: @EdMorton Good point, I have added `+0` to make it a numeric comparison. Perhaps  using PETA and   [Useless use of cat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) on the same page will  give us some interesting comments :-)

Comment: hadn't noticed that - lol ;-)